# How to add :id in link_to for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My goal is to create a way for sellers (User) to upload files to buyers (Buyer) in their, the User's,  Sales page (their sales history page). I am using Devise for user roles btw.

I have links, for example, I have the URL "**localhost:3000/orders/28/sales_uploads/new**" working so I can upload to the specific sale.

Though, within the Sales page for the User/seller, I want them to be able to upload the file to the buyer, (buyers buy product, seller then uploads file after purchase - each product/purchase will be custom), either through the sales page, preferably, or by clicking a link - which is where I'm having issues.  I want the seller to click a link "Upload" which then directs them to the page to upload the file for the order.

In the Sales page view, (views/sales_uploads/sales), I have

```
 <%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(@order, order) %>
```

but I get an error that there is no order_id.

How can I make it so the link links to the order with the order ID.

I have a

```
 <% @orders.each do |order| %>
```

so it cycles through and I can't figure out why it won't work.

Here is my github https://github.com/brandnamewater/digitalcommerce

As you'll see in the view mentioned above, I have the cycling working.  I'm assuming I'm having an issue elsewhere, possibly in the controller.  Though, I simply cannot figure it out.

Just in case, it's better off i link the entire app as there may be other issues I'm not aware of that are causing this.

I have only been coding regularly for a few weeks now and I'm sure it's something very basic to some of you but I can't figure it out.  I have been attempting this for 2 nights now and no other Google searches, Stack searches, etc. have helped.

Comment: Can you post the whole view, routes,rb and controllers? It's hard to tell what's going on with just a couple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code you're looking for is:

`<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(order) %>
<% end %>`

If you run `bin/rails routes | grep new_order_sales_upload` in your terminal it will provide some output which shows us the route helper method and also any parameters we need to pass into the route helper.

For your case it will output

```
new_order_sales_upload GET    /orders/:order_id/sales_uploads/new(.:format)                                            sales_uploads#new
```

This shows us the route helper is called `new_order_sales_upload` and that it expects a single parameter `:order_id`.

If you were to output `@order` in your view like `<%= @order.inspect %>` you would find it is `nil` because this instance variable is not being set.

Your loop `@orders.each` is setting a variable called `order`.

The reason your answer `<%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(order, @order) %>` works is because the route helper is only using the first variable `order` and the second one `@order` is `nil` and not being used.

You can read a lot more about routing in rails from the official guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Woah.  I tried so many different combinations, that may had been the one out of tons i didn't try.  I thought I had tried it with just "order" but must had used the wrong path.  I was switching my routes around at the time as well which only confused to situation.

thanks

Comment: Now I can't figure out how, when I upload the file, for it to completely save on the /sales page. like if you attempt another upload it will not allow it because it's already uploaded.  I can just keep uploading new files to each order id right now.

Comment: For instance, I can't [seem] to even be able to put an "edit" path on the /sales page

Comment: I updatd the github to the recent code.  When I upload, it gets saved, but doesn't register to the '/sales' page and I can conitnue to just upload.  I want it so there is 1 upload per order id.  I have tried using " <%= link_to video_tag(sales_upload.video_url(:thumb)), order.sales_upload if @sales_upload.video? %>" but it won't display.. it won't even display on the upload page where the file is uploaded.

What am I doing incorrectly here?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the order mixed up

It was :

```
<%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(@order, order) %>
```

and should had been:

```
 <%= link_to "Upload", new_order_sales_upload_path(order ,@order) %>
```